# Ant using the exec target to compile Coffee Scripts

Tags: ant, compiler-errors, exec, coffeescript

I have an Ant project that uses a bit of Coffee Script.  I would like Ant to compile all of the coffee instead of having another build step to compile it.  The coffee command line script that I want to use, that compiles all coffee files into synonomous js files (site.coffee compiles to site.js, app.coffee compiles to app.js):

```
coffee -c ./js/*.coffee
```

I created an Ant task that I assumed would run the same command, but am getting an error:

```
<target name="compilecoffee" description="Compiles coffeescript files">
    <exec executable="coffee">
        <arg value="-c ${env.WORKSPACE}js/*.coffee" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Now when I run `ant compilecoffee -Denv.WORKSPACE=./` I get the following error from Coffee:

```
Buildfile: /Users/dave/Workspace/ColdFusion/Mura-Themes/e123-1/build.xml

compilecoffee:
     [exec] 
     [exec] node.js:116
     [exec]         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
     [exec]         ^
     [exec] Error: unrecognized option: -c ./js/3_site.coffee
     [exec]     at OptionParser.parse (/Users/dave/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.1.1/package/lib/optparse.js:34:17)
     [exec]     at /Users/dave/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.1.1/package/lib/command.js:245:29
     [exec]     at Object.run (/Users/dave/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.1.1/package/lib/command.js:24:5)
     [exec]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dave/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.1.1/package/bin/coffee:7:27)
     [exec]     at Module._compile (module.js:373:26)
     [exec]     at Object..js (module.js:379:10)
     [exec]     at Module.load (module.js:305:31)
     [exec]     at Function._load (module.js:271:10)
     [exec]     at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:392:10)
     [exec]     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
     [exec] Result: 1
```

If I run, what I thought was, the coffee equivelant directly at the command line (`coffee -c ./js/*.coffee`) I get no errors and everything works as expected.  Am I using the exec target wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try =

```
<arg line="-c ${env.WORKSPACE}js/*.coffee" />
```

or use one arg value=... for every part of the command

```
<target name="compilecoffee" description="Compiles coffeescript files">
 <exec executable="coffee">
  <arg value="-c"/>
  <arg value="${env.WORKSPACE}js/*.coffee" />
 </exec>
</target>
```

coffee executable has to be on path or use =

```
<exec executable="full/path/to/coffee">
```

**EDIT**

as Dominic pointed out, the '*' won't be expanded, so you should use apply =

```
 <apply executable="coffee">
  <arg value="-c"/>
  <fileset dir="${env.WORKSPACE}js" includes="**/*.js"/>
 </apply>
```

see [Ant Manual apply task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) f.e. you may use parallel="true", means run the command only once, appending all files as arguments, if possible with coffee, to speed it up.

Comment: +1. Dave, you were having Ant run `coffee "-c ./js/3_site.coffee"`; the whitespace was part of the argument rather than separating arguments.

Comment: The separate args won't work as the glob won't be expanded by the shell.

Comment: Dominic, the build file does indeed expand the glob.  If I use `<arg line="-c ${env.WORKSPACE}js/*.coffee" />` I get the results as expected.  All CoffeeScript files are compiled into individual javascript files.  I have only tested with one coffeescript file so far, so it may fail if I add more than one.

Comment: OK, so arg line=... seems to work, but using the apply task may speed up things significantly, when you need to compile a lot of files, just use parallel="true" Dominics comment was related to the use of arg value, which is the recommended way, because arg line makes problems sometimes, so as a rule of thumb one should prefer arg value to arg line

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can achieve that by doing something like:

```
<target name="compile-coffee" description="Compiles coffeescript into the javascript dir">
  <exec executable="coffee">
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="--output" />
    <arg value="${javascript_dir}" />
    <arg value="${cofeescript_dir}" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

where javascript_dir points to your js directory (destination) and coffeescript_dir points to your coffeescript dir (origin).

*of course you can omit --output and javascript_dir if you just want to compile in place.